# How to remove and redirect .php for subdomains in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have the following codes to remove the .php extension and redirect the url without the suffix to the right file

```
# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I also have following codes to redirect m.example.com to www.example.com/m/

```
#mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m/$1 [L]
```

My question is, how should I do the same for files in the m folder, so that

1. when people enter m.example.com/test, it will go to m.example.com/test.php
2. when people go to m.example.com/test.php, the file will be shown, but the url is then changed to m.example.com/test ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think option 2 is possible

Comment: for 2nd one you can redirect/refresh the page to use m.example.com/test, but this is not advisable.

Comment: @Azrael: It is very much possible.

Comment: @anubhava without refresh or whatsoever?

Comment: Yes I have already submitted an answer to take care of both requirements.

Comment: @anubhava Ah I see ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine your rules and remove `http://www.example.com/` from target of redirect rule:

```
# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

#mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m/$1 [L]

# Resolve .php file for extension-less php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```